# show contact name as link but when click its given error not showing details page

Tags: controller, search

Showing Error :

> The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must begin with a letter and be unique, and must not include spaces, end with an underscore, or contain two consecutive underscores.

[image]

this is class code

```
public class democlass {
    public string searchboxstring {get;set;}
    public list < contact > result {get;set;}
    public Integer counter {get;set;}
    public democlass() {
        //result = new list<Contact>();
    }
    public void searchbox() {
        result = new List < Contact > ();
        result = [select Name, account.name from Contact where account.Name =: searchboxstring];
        counter = result.size();
    }
}
```

this is vf page code

```
<apex:page controller="democlass">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                <apex:inputText value="{!searchBoxstring}" label="Search" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchbox}">
                </apex:commandButton>
                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!result}" var="wl">
                    <apex:column>
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!wl.id}">{!wl.name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!wl.account.name}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!wl.id}" />
                </apex:pageblockTable>
                <apex:outputText>Total Record : {!counter} </apex:outputText>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the VF page outputlink

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!wl.id}">{!wl.name}</apex:outputLink>
```

remove the apex. You need to append apex in accessing standard pages.